# Metro style Beamer theme with in-built "Segoe UI" font

Tags: beamer, themes

Has anyone come across a Beamer theme having Microsoft Metro presentation style, in-built with "Segoe UI" font?

Comment: Hey, I'm porting Powerpoint/Powerdot themes to Beamer. Give me a link to a Metro style presentation (PPT/PPTX/PDF) and I _may_ give it a try.

Comment: Here is what I could get quickly: http://alesandrab.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/metro-ui-style-powerpoint-2010-template/

Comment: I've uploaded the Metro theme to https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/beamerports. Should I post an answer with the complete code, or just images, or...?

Answer (score 5):

Following my previous Beamer themes based on PowerPoint, I created a Metro style theme, based on the one you [linked](http://alesandrab.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/metro-ui-style-powerpoint-2010-template). It is available at https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/beamerports.

You can ask the theme to load the Microsoft font by passing it the `SegoeUI` option. It needs `fontspec`, so compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

#### Interesting parts from the code

For the block width to match the frametitle colorbox, I used the answer from [Make frametitle and block the same width in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181195).

I needed to redefine the logo handling mechanism like this:

```
\newcommand{\metro@logo}{}
\renewcommand{\logo}[1]{\renewcommand{\metro@logo}{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}
```

in order to be able to put the logo at different places.

I reproduced the navigation symbols from the PowerPoint template with TikZ and hyperref:

```
\newcommand{\metro@navigation}{% this uses the commands defined in beamerbasenavigation.sty
    \ifmetronav
    \begin{tikzpicture}[white, very thick, arrows=-{Straight Barb[length=3pt]}]
    \draw circle[radius=.25];
        \draw (.18,0) -- (-.18,0);
        \node[rectangle]{\hyperlinkframeendprev{\phantom{\rule{.5cm}{.5cm}}}};
    \draw (.7,0) circle[radius=.25];
        \filldraw (.62,.08) circle[radius=.05]
                  (.78,.08) circle[radius=.05]
                  (.62,-.08) circle[radius=.05]
                  (.78,-.08) circle[radius=.05];
        \node[rectangle] at (.7,0) {\hyperlinkpresentationstart{\phantom{\rule{.5cm}{.5cm}}}};
    \draw (1.4,0) circle[radius=.25];
        \draw (1.22,0) -- (1.58,0);
        \node[rectangle] at (1.4,0) {\hyperlinkframestartnext{\phantom{\rule{.5cm}{.5cm}}}};
    \draw (2.1,0) circle[radius=.25];
        \node[cross out, draw] at (2.1,0){};
        \node[rectangle] at (2.1,0){\Acrobatmenu{FullScreen}{\phantom{\rule{.5cm}{.5cm}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \fi
}
```

Pictures:

[image: example frame 1]
[image: example frame 2]